# Using Angular component in lazy loaded modules

Tags: angular

I want to use an Angular component in several parts of my application, including in a component inside a lazy loaded module. I don't know how to declare the component for using it in the lazy module. I'll show you some of the relevant parts of the different files:

**app.module.ts**

```
import { FpgTimeComponent } from './fpgTime/fpg-time.component';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
      AppComponent, 
      (...)
      FpgTimeComponent
```

**app.routing.ts**

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [

    { path: '', redirectTo: 'customer', pathMatch: 'full' },
    {
        path: 'customer',
        component: CustomerComponent
    },
    {
        path: 'lazy',
        loadChildren: 'app/lazy/lazy.module#LazyModule'
    }
];
```

**lazy.module.ts**

```
import { FpgTimeComponent } from '../fpgTime/fpg-time.component';

import { LazyComponent }   from './lazy.component';
import { routing } from './lazy.routing';

@NgModule({
    imports: [routing],
    declarations: [
        LazyComponent, 
        FpgTimeComponent
    ]
})
```

The app loads, but when I go to the lazy route, it throws the following error:

> Uncaught (in promise): Error: Type FpgTimeComponent is part of the
>   declarations of 2 modules: AppModule and LazyModule! Please consider
>   moving FpgTimeComponent to a higher module that imports AppModule and
>   LazyModule. You can also create a new NgModule that exports and
>   includes FpgTimeComponent then import that NgModule in AppModule and
>   LazyModule.

I'm not importing LazyModule anywhere, as it's being lazy loaded. So, how could I declare the component FpgTimeComponent to be able to use it inside the lazy module (and also in non-lazy components)?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`FpgTimeComponent` is not a part of the files of the lazy module that will be loaded, so you can't do that. Think about it, you are trying to import a component in the lazy module that the module knows nothing about since it isn't defined in that module, and it isn't defined in any other module you have imported in the `LazyModule`. So where is it going to get the component from?

Add `FpgTimeComponent` to a `SharedModule` and import the `SharedModule` in your `LazyModule`, or move the `FpgTimeComponent` to your `LazyModule`. Once you do one of those, it should work then.

The former might be a better approach because I can guarantee as you keep developing you will keep running into the same error with other components/lazy modules. If you are using the components in multiple places, then they should live in a `SharedModule` as [Angular best practices defines](https://angular.io/guide/sharing-ngmodules), and that `SharedModule` should be imported in all your lazy modules.

Here is an example.

**SharedModule:**

```
import { FpgTimeComponent } from './some/path';

@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        FpgTimeComponent
    ],
    exports: [
        FpgTimeComponent
    ]
})
```

**LazyModule:**

```
import { SharedModule } from '../shared/shared.module';

import { LazyComponent }   from './lazy.component';
import { routing } from './lazy.routing';

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        routing,
        SharedModule
    ],
    declarations: [
        LazyComponent
    ]
})
```

Comment: No problem. You may want to created a `shared` directory where the `SharedModule` will live, and your `FpgTimeComponent` component and all other shared components/directives/pipes/etc can all be in that `shared` directory, and you import/export them all in `SharedModule`, and then use that as you please within your app. Look at the official Angular example for a `SharedModule`: https://angular.io/guide/sharing-ngmodules

Comment: In a scenario where you have a `TestModule` (Lasy loaded module), where you dynamically render all the components in isolation (One by one, on request) for manual testing.. This means that all your components will have to reside in the `SharedModule`, as they are required by both the testing module and the other lazy loaded modules. *My question*: is there any use for the lazy loaded modules then, if _all_ the components need to be loaded via a shared module?

Comment: Why can't the Angular documentation be this clear? (thanks for the great example!)

Comment: ok, but what with app.module.ts ? Should I declare in 'declaration' section - FpgTimeComponent ?