# Does importing a component from a lazy loaded module elsewhere in the app circumvent lazy loading of this module in Angular 12?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-routing, angular-module, angular-lazyloading

We have some modules that come with their own navigation bars. These nav bars are actual components and they activated in the global `HeaderComponent` of the app as soon as the corresponding route is activated.

To pass the navigation component we use the `data`property of the route in `app-routing.module.ts`:

```
import { TestNavigationComponent } from './modules/test/components/test-navigation/test-navigation.component';

{
  path: 'test',
  loadChildren: () => import('./modules/test/test.module').then(m => m.TestModule),
  data: {
    nav: TestNavigationComponent
  },
},
```

While this works fine, I wonder:

**Does this circumvent lazy loading of the module? Is the module loaded anyway, because the navigation component is imported in the gobal `app-routing.module.ts` already?**

**If yes, how could I bundle the navigation component along with the module and pass it to the application's header?**

The naviagtion is rendered in the header component like this currently:

```
private updateNavigation(snapshot: ActivatedRouteSnapshot): void {
  const nav: Type<Component> = (snapshot.data as {nav: Type<Component>}).nav;

  if (nav instanceof Type) {
    if (nav === this.navigationType) {
      return;
    }

    this.clearNavigation();
    this.navigationType = nav;

    const factory: ComponentFactory<Component> = this.componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(nav);
    this.navigationComponentRef = this.navigationRef.createComponent(factory);

    return;
  }

  for (let childSnapshot of snapshot.children) {
    this.updateNavigation(childSnapshot);
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes if you directly import that component it will be eagerly loaded. For the second question, you can have 2 router outlets 1 for the application header and 1 for the main. And your lazy loaded module can fill the header outlet once it's requested. And this will bring more complexity to your application.

Comment: Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49536677/using-angular-component-in-lazy-loaded-modules) link.

Comment: @Eldar That was some great advice. I now have a router outlet for that, which makes everything much easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure exactly the reason you're passing the component itself rather than a string, which would allow you inside the module to just use a switch statement to give the correct component.

For visualizing what ends up in each module the `--stats-json` option for `ng build` is invaluable.

You can check to see where your components ended up with [webpack-bundle-analyzer](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/webpack-bundle-analyzer) using the command

```
npx webpack-bundle-analyzer dist/APPNAME/browser/stats.json
```

That would (for this case) show your component in your main bundle.

---

I misunderstood your question at first but I'll leave this here as an aside:

You can now lazy load just components (if they are standalone) in Angular 14 and above.

```
{
   path: 'faq',
   loadComponent: () => import('./lazy-faq-dialog/lazy-faq-dialog.component').then(m => m.LazyFaqDialogComponent)
}
```

Comment: That's actually a nice idea, to create the component programatically. I'll give it a shot. Unfortunately the project is still on v13 and will not be updated before February I think. The anaylzer bundle is awesome. Must check it out. Thanks for that also.

Comment: @lampshade good luck! I managed to update to v14 pretty easily as far as the base update went. But changing components over to standalone is what takes time. One of the biggest issues I came across is this one https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/46351 - so good to bear this in mind before you start.